# android convert View with ImageView to Bitmap but ImageView was lost

Tags: android

I have a Class inflateView which can infalte a view(with TextViews and ImageView) then return view.

```
Class inflateView(){
    public inflateView(){}
    public View getView(){
       View view = View.inflate(Context, R.layout.animal_share, null);
       ......
       set___TextViews
       ......
       ImageView imageView = (ImageView) view .findViewById(R.id.backdrop);
       Picasso.with(mContext).load(someURL).into(imageView);
       return view;
    }
}
```

Then new it in Activity , convert view to bitmap , bitmap to JPEG file , share this JPEG through Intent.

```
......
inflateView iV= new inflateView();
View view = iV.getView();
......
convert___view___to___bitmap
bitmap___to___file
share___this___file___through___Intent
......
```

The problem is the JPEG did not contain the URL pic, but other TextViews were good.

I have tried to assign the drawable resource to ImageView's src in XML,it worked fine, but loaded pic with Picasso did not work.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think I get the answer...

It's just because the view was returned before URL picture completely load.

Now I use imageview.setImageBitmap to make sure URL picture completely load before return.

But this may cause UI block a while.